# can't see and mount usb flash drive

Tags: raspbian, usb, mount

I have a fat32 usb flash drive that I am trying to mount on a raspberry 3b+.
the flash drive works perfectly on other computer.
when I connect it to the raspberry, I can't see it.

I tried `df -h`

> /dev/root        14G  7.4G  5.1G  60% 
> / devtmpfs        460M     0 
>   460M   0% /dev 
> tmpfs           464M  8.0K  464M   1% /dev/shm 
> tmpfs 
>   464M   13M  452M   3% /run 
> tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1%
>   /run/lock 
> tmpfs           464M     0  464M   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
>   /dev/mmcblk0p6   68M   23M   46M  33% /boot 
> tmpfs            93M  4.0K
>   93M   1% /run/user/1000 
> /dev/mmcblk0p5   30M  456K   28M   2%
>   /media/pi/SETTINGS1

`ls -l /dev/disk/by-label` , `sudo lsblk -o UUID,NAME,FSTYPE,SIZE,MOUNTPOINT,LABEL,MODEL`

I can't see it.

so I don't see how I can mount it ...

when I do dmesg after plugging it and un plugging it I see that:

> [85997.951060] usb 1-1.3: USB disconnect, device number 11 
>   [86004.570431] usb 1-1.3: new high-speed USB device number 12 using
>   dwc_otg 
>  [86004.712217] usb 1-1.3: New USB device found, idVendor=058f,
>   idProduct=1234 
>  [86004.712235] usb 1-1.3: New USB device strings:
>   Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=0 
>  [86004.712244] usb 1-1.3: Product:
>   Mass Storage Device 
>  [86004.712253] usb 1-1.3: Manufacturer: Alcor
>   Micro 
>  [86004.715565] usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0: USB Mass Storage device
>   detected  
>  [86004.723838] scsi host0: usb-storage 1-1.3:1.0
>   [86005.761479] scsi 0:0:0:0: Direct-Access     Generic  USB Flash Disk
>   7.76 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4 
>  [86005.762422] sd 0:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg0 type 0 
>  [86005.772081] sd 0:0:0:0: 
>  [sda] Attached SCSI removable
>   disk

so it does something but how can I mount it ?

Comment: it is probably mounted automatically

Comment: so how can I see it ? because it's not in /media, in /mnt, as I said I can't see it using df -h

Comment: Please add the output of 'df -h' and  'sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda' to the question. Do you have another usb flash drive to test what the similar dmesg output is?

Comment: done for df -h, for the other one , can't open /def/sda: no medium found.
I don't have any other usb flash drive with me for now but I'll try to get one soon

Comment: It's definitely not attaching correctly, but I don't know how to dig into why.

Comment: it works if I unplug the mouse and keyboard... must be a power problem

Comment: `/def/sda` for future reference: it's 'dev' (as in 'devices'), not 'def'

Comment: sorry for the typo, I write /dev during my tests. I made the typo in the comment here